# What would be a good python library to use to write a portable version of pacman with nice graphics?

Tags: python, pygame, pacman

I basically want to make a clone of the classic game Pacman using Python. I would like to keep all the original graphics, sounds, etc. Perhaps being able to have the game in windowed mode would be useful.

With Java I would just use Swing and be done with it. But I'd really like to use Python and make it possible for the game to work on all major platforms with minimal effort from the users.

I've used pygame previously but felt that it was a bit 'hacky' and not all that intuitive to use.

Comment: and what about this: http://www.pygame.org/projects/20/426/

Comment: @joaquin: I didn't say it couldn't be done with pygame. I would just prefer to use a different framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro). Qt isn't only meant for games but it has a [QGraphicsView](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qgraphicsview.html) and an [OpenGL widget](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qglwidget.html) where you can render from Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with Tkinter about as easily (or easier) than most other toolkits. Since pac-man graphics set the bar pretty low you could code this all by using the canvas widget. This is arguably the most portable solution since Tkinter is the official, bundled GUI toolkit so you won't require people to download any extra libraries.

The canvas widget gives you a nice vector-based drawing surface, with nice tagging abilities that let you easily move drawn objects. It supports all the basic drawing primitives -- lines, circles, etc. as well as being able to embed bitmap graphics and even other widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org)! It's pretty well organized so very easy to pick-up and powerful enough to create simple games (like pacman) real quick. It's available on Windows, Mac OSX and Linux.